# Prevent failure in conditional insert in mysql database

Tags: mysql, aws, concurrency, condition, hibernate

The infrastructure of our system looks like this.

An AWS lambda function receives requests such as (accountId, .....). It creates an entry in the MySQL database using a newly generated UUID as caseId. (caseId, accountId, ....).

The insert is a conditional insert operation discussed in detail below.

I am able to avoid race condition by setting transaction isolation to SERIALIZABLE. However, the issue is that I do not have any control over how many concurrent requests will be successfully processed.

For example, consider following concurrent requests.

```
request  | accountId | field1 | ...  <condition>
 1         a1          value1   ....   true     --- create a new entry with caseId Idxxx
 2         a1          value2   ....   false    --- update existing entry with caseId Idxxx 
 3         a1          value3   ....   false    --- update existing entry with caseId Idxxx 
 4         a1          value4   ....   false    --- update existing entry with caseId Idxxx
```

With our current implementation we are getting CannotAquireLockException.
What are the ways in which I can avoid retry failures (CannotAquireLockException) ?

The detailed table schema and condition are described below:

The database is a mysql database system with the following table schema.

```
Table1: case table

|caseId(PK) | accountId | status |  .....

Table2: case reopen table

|caseId(FK)| casereopenId(PK)| caseReopenTime|

Table3: Alert table

Id (incrementing id) | alertId | accountId |
```

The lambda function tries to "create" a case in the database.

the create wrapper, generates a UUID for caseId.

The goal is :

- check if an accountId already exists in case table.
- if it does, then

  - check if status is OPEN
  - get the caseId for the accountId.
  - check if the caseId is present in case reopen table.

    - if above condition is false, then add an entry into the case table.

Thanks!

Comment: Implement everything on the MySQL side (in query or stored procedure form). Use `INSERT .. ODKU` (create proper unique indices). PS. Your 'The goal is' is partial - there are variants without listed action.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with `SERIALIZABLE`.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT caseid, status, ... FROM ... WHERE ... FOR UPDATE;
check `status`, do some processing
optionally do
    INSERT ...
COMMIT;
```

With that logic, you can handle lots of concurrent actions.